# How to have recurring date events?

Tags: 8, datetime

It appears there is no End Date or Date Repeat options for the datetime field in Drupal 8.

Are there any contrib options for recurring events in Drupal 8?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

<strike>As of 2016/03/04, these are open issues in Drupal 8.  See [Support for end date](https://www.drupal.org/node/2161337) and [D8: Date repeat feature requests](https://www.drupal.org/node/2305073).  The decision was made to move these from contrib into core, but they are complicated issues, and unfortunately touch the exact same portions of code, so working on them simultaneously is difficult.</strike>

As of 2016/12/07, [support for end date](https://www.drupal.org/node/2161337) is officially part of core, starting with 8.2.0.  It is looking like [the date repeat feature](https://www.drupal.org/node/2305073) is going to end up in the [datetime extras module](https://www.drupal.org/project/datetime_extras) as part of contrib, and not core.  However, work on this is still preliminary.

Answer (score 6):

There is a new module named [Date Recur Field (repeating dates)](https://www.drupal.org/project/date_recur) that can help you.

> Recurring dates, i.e. date repeat, for Drupal 8.
>
> Provides a new field type that supports repeating dates via recurrence
>   rules (RRule). For RRule compilation, php-rrule is used.

If you need integration with [Calendar](https://www.drupal.org/project/date_recur) module you need to apply [Patch for calendar module](https://www.drupal.org/node/2820803).

I think that the module needs integration with the Datetime Range core module because for the moment to show a multi days event in Calendar you need the [Improve the Views integration for DateRange fields](https://www.drupal.org/node/2786577#comment-11860283) patch.

Comment: Note that date_recur is currently alpha and shouldn't be used on production sites (I can't find any indication of when a beta might be released).

Answer (score 3):

There's a sandbox: https://www.drupal.org/sandbox/frando/2775015 - didn't test it, though.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Recurring events](https://www.drupal.org/project/recurring_events)

**Information about Recurring events**

The module allows site editors to create and manage events which recur in a variety of ways - including consecutively, daily, weekly, monthly, and custom recurrence configurations. An event series comprises of multiple event instances, each of which inherits data from the series, but can also be managed and viewed independently from the series itself, this offers great flexibility when it comes to modifying event instance dates and times or removing them altogether.

The module also has four submodules:

- recurring_events_registration enables registration for events
- recurring_events_views which swaps entity lists for flexible views
- recurring_events_reminders which allows sending of reminder emails for event registrants
- group_recurring_events_series which allows the event series entities to be configured as groups with the Group module.

A part of edit form of event type
[image: A part of edit form of event type]